# Threads, Object state

Tags: java, multithreading, object, thread-safety, java-threads

```
Class A{

private boolean connected = false;

public void doAction(){

if(connected){
//do something
}
else{
//do this
  }
   }

public void setConnected(boolean flag)
    {
       this.connected = flag;
    }
  }
```

I have above code in my project and it is a singleton. `setConnected()` method will be triggered upon some condition(it will be triggered only once).
`doAction()` method is invoked periodically by the scheduler for performing some operations.

My question is if the state of the singleton object is modified after construction( by calling `setConnected()`), the updated state is visible to the further invoking method calls (periodical invocation of `doAction()`)?(note: the connected variable is not volatile).

Comment: is your doAction and setConnected method called from different thread?

Comment: yes, it is called from different thread

Comment: So I strongly recommend using volatile in your case. Go through my answer for more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your `connected` variable is not `volatile` that means, it does not `guarantee` that all other thread get updated value after any write operation by some other thread. So I will recommend using `volatile` for your use case. volatile keyword ensures all thread see the `most recent updated` value.

**Edited:**

A non-volatile variable also can be refreshed on the CPU cache in different condition.

1. A thread can also be swapped out of its CPU forcing it to reload it cache memory when it gets the next time slice.
2. A thread flushes all of its updated value when it exit / or finished.If you are creating a new thread (to call `doAction`) after the thread (which called your `setConnected` method) and it successfully finished it will get the updated value as a new thread will create a new context for it every time.

Comment: you mean, further method invocations never happen to see the updated value to connected variable? if yes, then when does thread cached values publish to main memory?

Comment: thanks for your response, i have one more doubt, in case of j2ee environment, threads are maintained in common threadpool, when execution completes, the thread will not be terminated, instead it will return to threadpool for  further request processing. in that case as you mentioned in point 2, the thread cache flush to main memory?

Comment: @girishbabu By point - 2 I am trying to explain that if a thread finishes its execution then update will be available on the main memory. So, after finishing that thread if you create any thread then it will see the most recent value. Yes, In case of the thread pool flushing may be late. So, to ensure read-write on updated value use volatile / synchronized / join etc.